# Visual Basic subprocedure issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, event-handling

I'm working on some .NET code in visual studio web developer and I'm having an issue.  When I double click on a button in design view, instead of loading a subprocedure, all it does is highlight this: `<asp:Button ID="btnEnter" runat="server" Text="Enter" onclick="btnEnter_Click" />`

When I try to run that just to see what happens, I get this error: 
`Line 8:      <asp:Button ID="btnEnter" runat="server"`
`Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'btnEnter_Click' is not a member of 'ASP.default_aspx'.`

If I erase the `onclick="btnEnter_Click"` and run it, it works.  Either way though, when I double click the button / element, shouldn't it create a subprocedure for me that looks something like?
`Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)`

`End Sub`

I've tried entering that manaully but the keywords don't turn blue or any sort of color, and when I run it, it just shows up as text on the webform with my other elements.  Here is all I have so far:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB"%>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter a person's name below"></asp:Label>
<p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStudentName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnEnter" runat="server"
       Text="Enter" onclick="btnEnter_Click" />
</p>
<p>
<asp:Button ID="btnDisplay" runat="server" Text="Display all and exit" />
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>
</p>
<p>
<asp:Label ID="lbl3" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl4" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl5" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>
</p>
    </form>
```

Edit:

When I enter my code inside the default.aspx.vb file, it highlights keywords and such, but it can't reference the elements I created in the design view.

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class

```
Class Lab1
Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
Public Const length As Integer = 3
Shared counter2 As Integer = 0
Public Shared studentList As String() = New String(2) {}
Protected Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = "Enter a person's name"

    Dim studentName As [String] = txtStudentName.Text
    If studentList.Length <= length Then
        If txtStudentName.Text <> "" Then
            Dim match As [Boolean] = True
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            While counter2 >= i
                If studentList(i) IsNot Nothing Then
                    If studentList(i).ToUpper() = txtStudentName.Text.ToUpper() Then
                        match = False
                        Label1.Text = "This name has already been used"
                    End If
                End If
                i += 1
            End While
            If match = True Then
                studentList(counter2) = txtStudentName.Text
                counter2 += 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Page` declaration seems to say you are using `inline` style:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB"%>
```

Which means your code is/should be *within*  `aspx` file itself in a `script runat="server"` tag:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<!DOCTYPE html> 

<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'Do something
    End Sub

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>    
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />    
      </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

However, your other code indicates you seem to want to use `code-behind` model, where you have `.vb` files (e.g. `foo.aspx.vb`)

The `Page` is declared like this for web sites (for web *applications* it will say `CodeBehind="foo.aspx.vb"`):

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="foo.aspx.vb" Inherits="foo" %>
```

- You will find a `foo.asp.vb` file in your project
- it's class name will be the name of your file (foo)
- your code should be scoped to this class (I'm not sure what `Class Lab1` in your post above is for....

`foo.aspx.vb`:

```
Partial Class foo
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Do something
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

The "fix" is for you to:

- choose which model you want to write code: `inline` or `code-behind`
- declare the `Page` appropriately
- for `inline`, your code will be in the aspx file itself
- for `code-behind`, your code will live, and should be encapsulated within the `Class file` of the page.

  - The `Page` declaration actually says so:

    - `CodeFile="foo.aspx.vb"` is the file where the code is
    - `Inherits="foo"` is the `Partial Class` in the file (`Partial Class foo`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click

End Sub
```

Here, **btnEnter_Click** is your event name and use the **Handles** keyword at the end of a procedure declaration to cause it to handle events raised by an object variable

Comment: I added that to the Default.aspx page before the form starts, but after the <%@ Page Title ..%> and it still wasn't recognized as keywords, and I still got the error when I tried to run it.  I tried putting it in the Default.aspx.vb file and it recognized the keywords and such but then I don't know if you can reference the form ID's because it was thinking that I was using undeclared variables.

Comment: I created a new "Visual Basic ASP.NET Website" and have the files - about.aspx, about.aspx.vb, Default.aspx, default.aspx.vb, global.asax, site.master, site.master.vb, and web.config.  I am trying to translate my C# code I just created into VB and in C#, I just wrote my code in the Default.aspx file, where the forms and elements are declared

Comment: So problem is your control is not visible in VB file.. right..? Is there any error when run this page..?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "control" but this is the code that I'm running...[link](http://tinypic.com/r/1zqrd01/5) It only turns blue when it's in the default.aspx.vb file, but as you can see by the picture, it doesn't recognize any of the variables on the form.  But if I put the code on the form page, then it doesn't recognize it as VB code, but instead plaintext.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to answer your question.